# What are the possible uses of Encode Thoughts?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips, mind-control

I see a lot of confusion about what this spell can, and cannot do. Can anyone give some suggestions, on the possible in game uses of the spell?

For example, I see many suggesting that the spell will enable them to transfer thoughts around from person to person, but the only ability I see, is the ability to materialize ones own thoughts into a 'thought strand' and, using 'Detect thoughts' or 'Alter Memory', also extract and materialize other creatures thoughts into a 'thought strand'. But besides being able to read a thought strand at a later time (within 8 hours) I don't see anything to suggest that you would be able to cram a thought from creature A into the mind of creature B? Or am I missing something?

Encode Thoughts can be found in the *Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica*, in print or on [DnDBeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/encode-thoughts).

Comment: Have you read the source book for the spell, Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica?

Comment: I think this question can be focused down to simply asking whether the spell can do a specific thing or things. As it is ("shopping" for suggestions aside), it would be too broad to answer as a proper question. If you can focus this question with specific examples of what you're trying to achieve, I think we can answer this.

Comment: Oh, okay. I believe I have seen multiple examples of people just asking for examples of what a spell can do? If there is discontent with answering a question that looks for clarification on what a spell can do, then I don't understand why? I'll try to narrow my query.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  What is it about the spell's text or description that has you puzzled? (I'd like to help you focus this question, but I do not have the Ravnica book, and I don't use material from it, so I can't help with how to make it better).

Comment: Regarding other questions about what spells can do, they tend to be questions like "Can spell X cause effect Y?" or "If I use spell X in situation Z, what happens?". What's making this question in particular seem too broad is asking for "inspiring suggestions" on any possible use, in any possible situation. It's unbounded, and the most stack-friendly answer you are likely to receive would be "whatever the spell says it can do", which is probably not very helpful.

Comment: Hehe, okay :) I think I understand what you are all saying. But does that also mean that questions just wanting examples of a spells effect are rules out? I understand why a question asking for inspiration on what kind of creatures seeming would enable players to transform into, would be to broad. When I search for clarification on for example a spell, and I see confusion and misunderstanding on other pages, I think, "hey, other people obviously also struggle with understanding how this particular spell work, lets create a "bulletin" that has the correct information".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### *Encode Thoughts* provides access to a secret communication channel

Think of this spell as similar to Thieves' Cant or Druidic: it's a way to communicate with other people that possess the same ability without anyone else being able to listen in, and often without them even knowing that the communication took place at all. The spell is learned only by members of [House Dimir](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/ggtr/house-dimir) in Ravnica, which is all about secrets and clandestine operations. If you're a spellcaster in House Dimir, your orders are often delivered via thought strands:

> Messages to agents are funneled through thought strands (see “Spell: *Encode Thoughts*” later in this section) and telepathic couriers.

(Note: If you're not a spellcaster, that's where the telepathic couriers come in.)

As for possible uses, there are many obvious ones, generally involving some kind of espionage or secret activity. It's all the same kind of things you might use Thieves' Cant for, with the added benefit of not needing to actually speak to your contact at all.

#### Get your DM's approval

Obviously, this spell is only useful if you have contacts in the world who *also* know the spell. In that sense, the existence of this spell in the world implies a *lot* of world building on the part of the DM. So you should really talk to your DM before deciding to learn this spell to make sure they are prepared to integrate its use into the world at large, and thereby give you something to do with it.

Comment: Awesome answer! I think I now understand what part of my question seemed to broad.